# How to load MediaWiki's WikiEditor?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have an old skin that I need to adapt to the new MediaWiki 1.18 which has this new WikiEditor. If I set the skin to `Simple` or any other theme than the custom theme, then I see the WYSIWYG editor (WikiEditor), but if I use a custom skin I don't see it.

I think I'm missing something, I've wasted half a work day trying to figure what am I missing but the skin seems to be just like the other skins. I checked MediaWiki homepage but they don't tell what do I need to do to get this WikiEditor to load.

To confirm: the WikiEditor source codes are never loaded, i.e. the ResourceLoader does not load them, but I do not know how to make it load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in 1.18, skins should use the following instead of writing their own HTML HEAD sections:

```
$this->html( 'headelement' );
```

headelement includes the opening body tag, so everything between that and doctype should be removed from your legacy code.  This will of course break backwards compatibility with pre-1.18 mediawiki.

Your skin may also need to be modified to use SkinTemplate rather than BaseTemplate in its class declaration.

Answer (score 6):

From [Extension:WikiEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiEditor):

```
For 1.18 and later the extension already comes with your MediaWiki package.
You only need to install and configure it as described below:

Add the following line to your LocalSettings.php:

require_once( "$IP/extensions/WikiEditor/WikiEditor.php" );

To enable use of WikiEditor by default but still allow users to disable it in preferences, use something like...

$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar-cgd'] = 1;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-preview'] = 1;
```

Comment: I already have it. It works for the Simple theme but not older 1.16 themes.

Comment: Have you [validated](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) your custom skins css code?  I have two custom skins on my wiki (currently running 1.17.1) and they are causing all kinds of issues.  WikiMedia Bugzilla links: "_@import styles broken in <skin>.css in user and site modules_" -- [35562](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35562) or the "_WikiEditor issues (tracking)_" thread -- [24493](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24493) may be of some use to you, or at very least -- point you in the correct direction.